# Telerik RadDock padding issue

Tags: winforms, telerik, raddocking

I have set the RadDock padding to (0,0,0,0) on one of my windorms, but every time I build the project, the padding gets reset to the default size (5,5,5,5).

This is the first time I've encountered this problem, I've done this on numerous other forms in the past few days without any issues. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that there is a property called 'RootElement' which also controls the RadDock padding. The issue was resolved when I've set its sub property 'Padding' to (0,0,0,0).